# how change style row select now in datarepeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

i want change style linkbutton row that the showing.
i want use this code , but keeps style  before select linkbutton row after select other linkbutton row .

html codes:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="div">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" aID="pnl">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkbtn" PostBackUrl='<%#"WebForm1.aspx?Id="+Eval("CategoryGalleryID")%>'
                        Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

C# Codes:

```
        protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string ID = Page.Request.QueryString.Get("ID");
        LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtn");
        lnkbtn.Font.Bold= true;
    }
```

Comment: We are having a bit of a language barrier here i'm afraid, and I dont mean the programming language. ..I really can't figure out what you are trying to ask..

Comment: hi Damien Overeem.
i want change style selection LinkButton .
but after click new LinkButton , keep style old clicked LinkButton.
Whereas i want only change style Currently selected LinkButton

Comment: i want change style latest LinkButton seleceted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Use

```
lnkbtn.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold;");
```

Eg.:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string ID = Page.Request.QueryString.Get("ID");
    LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtn");
    lnkbtn.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold;");
}
```

---

I think you want to change the style of the selected LinkButton.

You can do that using CSS.

Eg.:

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Check this for detail:

[Styling Links](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

Comment: i want change style latest LinkButton seleceted.

Comment: find your i want this link.
http://dc407.4shared.com/img/gKcFkjqK/s3/0.17497210994654322/222_2.jpg

Comment: i want only change style Currently selected LinkButton